# sizer.replace() paints "over" old sizercontent

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am rather new to wx/python so please excuse if this is stupid or ill described.

I am substituting a nested sizer with a new one as shown in the snippet below. after some tinkering everything seems to work out but the re-drawing of the parent-sizer.
the content of the old nested sizer remains and gets "painted" over with the new sizer content despite my sizer.Layout()

system setup:
- python 2.5.5.2 and 2.6.4
- wxpython 2.8

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, title='test')

class Test(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = Frame()
        self.panel = wx.Panel(frame)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('red')
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        button = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'TEST')

        self.hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.hsizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'nacknack'))

        self.sizer.Add(button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_test_button, button)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'FOOO')
        self.sizer.Add(self.text)
        self.sizer.Add(self.hsizer)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        frame.Show()
        return True

    def on_test_button(self, evt):
        tmpsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        tmpsizer.Add(self.makesizer())
        tmpitem = tmpsizer.GetChildren()[0]

        self.sizer.Replace(2, tmpitem)
        self.sizer.Layout()

    def makesizer(self):
        testsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        testsizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'testsizer'))
        return testsizer

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = Test()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through your code (and it wasn't easy - please consider formatting it differently next time - maybe grouping the `self.sizer.add` functions or something) I think I discovered your bug:

When you call `Replace` on a sizer, the item being replaced is not *destroyed* but becomes *no longer managed by the sizer*. You need to hide or destroy the old window (the `wx.StaticText`)

As mentioned in the wxWidgets docs:

`virtual bool Replace (wxWindow *oldwin, wxWindow *newwin, bool recursive=false)
    Detaches the given oldwin from the sizer and replaces it with the given newwin.`